# R: plotROC main title cannot be changed from default

Tags: r, plot, par

I use the `plotROC` from `hmeasure`-package to (try to) plot an ROC curve. I get a plot like shown below. The code I used is:

```
require(hmeasure)
predictions_LIMO <- data.frame(df)  
h_LIMO <- HMeasure(mydata$churn, predictions_LIMO) 
plotROC(h_LIMO,which=1)
```

If I try to customize the main title, I get the two titles overlapping each other, like shown in the lower picture. The additional code is:

```
title("ROC curve for LIMO4 to LIMO8")
```

Is there a way to get rid of the automatically assigned title? I tried `main=0` but received `unused argument (main = 0)`.

In the `?plotROC` I did not find anything about that.

Thanks for any advice (maybe also on different packages that I can use to circumvent the problem)!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is hard coded into the function. You'd have to create your own copy of `plotROC` and modify the line where it specifies the title (it's very easy to find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joran said, it's hard-coded. Here's a quick hack if you don't want to mess with the `plotROC` function. You can "cover" the existing title with a white rectangle and then add your own title. For example:

```
# Adjust location of rectangle as needed. These coordinates should work
# for the graph you posted.
rect(0, 1.1, 1, 1.7, xpd=TRUE, col="white", border="white")
title("My Title")
```

Comment: this worked very fine! Thank you. At some point I will have to do some function-recoding, finally, but for now I'm glad I do not have to get into that.